# submit button not clickable

Tags: php, forms, button

this is a wp theme and some users complaining about submit button is not clickable. There is no pattern of this issue, sometimes android sometimes ios, sometimes firefox sometimes chrome users say the button is not clickable.
I tried some solutions mentioned here but did not work.
I have never experienced the problem. But there are significant number of people reporting this issue.

```
<form id="submit_question" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" id="qa_nonce" name="qa_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'insert_question' ); ?>">
                    <input id="add_tag_text" type="hidden" value="<?php printf(__("You must have %d points to add tag. Current, you have to select existing tags.", ET_DOMAIN), $privi->create_tag  ); ?>" />
                    <div class="form-post">
                        <input type="text" name="post_title" id="question_title" placeholder="<?php _e("Your Question", ET_DOMAIN) ?>">
                        <span id="charNum"><?php echo ae_get_option('max_width_title', 150);?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-post">
                        <div class="select-categories-wrapper">
                            <div class="select-categories">
                                <select class="select-grey-bg" id="" name="question_category">
                                    <option value=""><?php _e("Select Category",ET_DOMAIN) ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                        $terms = get_terms( 'question_category', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby'    => 'term_group' ) );
                                        $value_type = 'slug';
                                        foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                            if($term->parent == 0){
                                                if($value_type == 'slug') {
                                                    echo "<option value='".$term->slug."'>";
                                                } elseif($value_type == 'id') {
                                                    echo "<option value='".$term->term_id."'>";
                                                }
                                                echo $term->name;
                                                echo "</option>";
                                                foreach ($terms as $value) {
                                                    if($term->term_id == $value->parent){
                                                        if($value_type == 'slug') {
                                                            echo "<option value='".$value->slug."'>";
                                                        } elseif($value_type == 'id') {
                                                            echo "<option value='".$value->term_id."'>";
                                                        }
                                                            echo "--".$value->name;
                                                        echo "</option>";
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php if(ae_get_option('ae_upload_images')){ ?>
                    <div class="form-post container_upload">
                        <div class="upload_image" id="mobile_images_upload_container">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="mobile_images_upload_browse_button"><i class="fa fa-image"></i><?php _e("Insert Image", ET_DOMAIN); ?></a>
                            <span class="et_ajaxnonce" id="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'et_upload_images' ); ?>"></span>
                            <span id="mobile_images_upload_text">
                            <?php
                            global $max_file_size;
                            printf(__("Size must be less than < %sMB.", ET_DOMAIN),$max_file_size);
                            ?>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="form-post">
                         <?php wp_editor( '', 'post_content', editor_settings_mobile() );?>
                        <!-- <textarea name="post_content" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="<?php _e("Your Description", ET_DOMAIN) ?>"></textarea> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-post">
                        <input  data-provide="typeahead" type="text" name="" id="question_tags" placeholder="<?php _e('Tag(max 5 tags)',ET_DOMAIN) ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <ul class="post-question-tags" id="tag_list"></ul>
                    <?php if(ae_get_option('gg_question_captcha') && $role != 'administrator'){ ?>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="container_captcha">
                            <div class="gg-captcha form-group">
                            <?php ae_gg_recaptcha(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="group-btn-post">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-5 no-pad-left"><span class="text"><?php _e("Ask a Question", ET_DOMAIN) ?></span></div>
                                <div class="col-xs-7 text-right">
                                    <button type="submit" class="submit-post-question"><?php _e("Submit", ET_DOMAIN) ?></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: May you wanna try it with `<input type="submit" class="submit-post-question" value="Submit">`

Comment: I tried but did not work, then it appeared that some users (which are experiencing not clickable button) did not put any text in the content area, and even its not required in the desktop version, in the mobile (top code) version it is required to put text in the content area. When they write someting there, buttons turn in to clickable. So new challenge is why it is required :)